# Does Varnish cache 404s by default?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I was really surprised that I've had this much trouble finding this answer anywhere, but I can't.

With the built-in VCL in `vcl_recv`, etc., in Varnish 4.0+, does Varnish cache 404 responses by default?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only the following status codes will be cached by default:

```
200: OK
203: Non-Authoritative Information
300: Multiple Choices
301: Moved Permanently
302: Moved Temporarily
304: Not modified
307: Temporary Redirect
410: Gone
404: Not Found
```

Source: http://book.varnish-software.com/4.0/chapters/VCL_Basics.html